# Yellowing of very young garlic plants

Tags: garlic

Garlic planted last autumn is showing some yellowing on the tips of the leaves. Some tips are also dry. I am unsure why this is happening. The winter was relatively mild, with temperature no lower than -10°C. Garlic plants were covered in snow for a few weeks.

Are the plants missing nutrients, water or is this normal for post winter?

[image]
[image]
[image]